# Which is faster a select sub-query or a left outer join in a paginated result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

When querying with MSSQL what is the most efficient way to grab a single column from a computed table and connect it to a result set.

Tables: `mytable` = 20k rows index on `mytable.col1`, `othertable` = 30k rows, no index on `othertable.col1`

**Inline Query** - Runs an query in the select statement

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, 
    col4 = (SELECT min(col5) FROM othertable o WHERE m.col1 = o.col1)
    row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY somerow) 
    FROM mytable m
) as paged
WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 25
```

**Join Query** - Joins our table onto the computed table

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, o2.col5again
    row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY somerow) 
    FROM mytable m
    JOIN (SELECT col1, min(col5) as col5again FROM othertable o GROUP BY col1) as o2 ON o2.col1 = m.col1
) as paged
WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 25
```

My gut instinct was the `JOIN` was faster. Yet, upon testing the inline query would finish in an average of 7 seconds while the other query would take >30 seconds when executed in MSSQL studio.

1. Is using an inline select query really the best way to inject the single column?
2. Does the query optimized wait to run the inline `SELECT()` statement until after the results have been paged, would that explain the different in running time?

FYI: In my specific example we added an index to `othertable.col1` and it reduced the query time to 0s, but this question focuses more on whether the JOIN versus SELECT() is better.

Comment: Do these both compile? Looks like innermost query is missing `FROM`.

Comment: Added the `FROM`, I haven't tested this exact query since I sanitized this down from the actual example I ran into so that it would making a cleaner question on SO.

Comment: The best way to find out: run both queries with `set statistics time on` to view their duration.  You can also run a trace to watch duration.

Comment: You do not need to join to a subquery in your second example. Just directly join to `othertable` and put your `GROUP BY` in the enclosing query. The query engine will apply the `GROUP BY` to `othertable` before it executes the join anyway, and your query will have fewer levels.

Comment: These two queries look like they will have the exact same query plan. Have you checked the query plan for both?

Comment: I have not checked the query plan for both. But I do know that the inline query runs about 10x faster than the join query when we add an `ORDER BY` to the interior query. In my original problem it was the combination of both the `join` and the `order by` which caused the query to fail (taking longer than 60s to execute). If the join was there, OR the order by was there, it would return promptly, but not with both. Using the inline style helped to speed it up, but I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Regarding the `group by` comment, wouldn't I have to repeat every column in the select list in the group by statement? Which in this example is only 3, but in the my actual circumstance would be 20+ columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance tuning is an art that involves understanding why plans are created the way they are, what each piece in the plan does, and how you can influence a more efficient path to be chosen.

Missing covering indexes will cause scans (excessive reads). Too many indexes will slow down your DUI's (Deletes, Updates, and Inserts). Outdated or missing statistics will cause the wrong join algorithm to be used and/or an inaccurate estimated row count (which could lead to paging).

Run both queries in the same window and include the actual execution plan. This will split the plans up and tell you which one is more expensive. It will give you missing index hints. As you get better at reading plans, you'll learn how to improve your query performance.