# Does mysql optimize the IN clause

Tags: mysql, query-performance

When i execute this mysql query like

`select * from t1 where colomn1 in (select colomn1 from t2)` ,

what really happens?

**I want to know if it executes the inner statement for every row**?

PS: I have 300,000 rows in t1 and 50,000 rows in t2 and it is taking a hell of a time.

Comment: make your column1 index or unique field in table t1 and column1 in table t2, it will help a lot

Comment: i have used join in first place but it too didn't work

Comment: how didnt work? was slow? returned different data? as uvais mentioned indexing will help for joins and for subqueries

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subquery v/s inner join in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052596/subquery-v-s-inner-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Uriel_SVK it was slow...i waited for 2-3 minutes...then i canceled the query..

Comment: @user217869 are you using any indexes? You should have indexes at least on `t1.column1` and `t2.column1`. Also it should be better to use `JOIN`

Comment: indexing works, but i want to know what really happens when this query gets executed !!

Answer (score 1):

I'm flabbergasted to see that everyone points out to use `JOIN` as if it is the same thing. **IT IS NOT!**, not with the information given here. E.g. What if `t2.column1` has doubles ?

=> Assuming there are no doubles in `t2.column1`, then yes, put a `UNIQUE INDEX` on said column and use a JOIN construction as it is more readable and easier to maintain. If it is going to be faster; that depends on what the query engine makes from it. In MSSQL the query-optimizer (probably) would consider them the same thing; maybe MySQL is 'not so eager' to recognize this... don't know.

=> Assuming there can be doubles in `t2.column1`, put a (non-unique) `INDEX` on said column and rewrite the `WHERE IN (SELECT ..)` into a `WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.column1 = t1.column1)`. Again, mostly for readability and ease of maintenance; most likely the query engine will treat them the same...

The things to remember are

- Always make sure you have proper indexing (but don't go overboard)
- Always realize that what really happens will be an *interpretation* of your sql-code; not a 'direct translation'. You can write the same functionality in different ways to achieve the same goal. And some of these are indeed more resilient to different scenarios.

If you only have 10 rows, pretty much everything works. If you have 10M rows it could be worth examining the query plan... which most-likely will be different from the one with 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

A join would be quicker, viz:

```
select t1.* from t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.colomn1=t2.colomn1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.column1=t2.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do indexing in column1 and then you can use inner join
for [indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON t1 (col1);
CREATE INDEX index2 ON t2 (col2);
select t1.* from t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.colomn1=t2.colomn1
```