# which gives best performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

Please go through the following query, and help me to understand which one is efficient and how?

In logical query execution, where clause will be executed after completion of join, so I thought the query 2 will gain the performance benefits. Is that right?

**Query 1:**

```
select a.*, b.* 
from table1 a 
join table2 b on a.colA = b.colA
where a.ColB = 'Somevalue'
```

**Query 2:**

```
select a.*, b.* 
from 
    (select * 
     from table1 
     where ColB = 'Somevalue' ) a 
join table2 b on a.colA = b.colA
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052596/subquery-v-s-inner-join-in-sql-server

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select a.*, b.* 
from table1 a 
join table2 b on a.colA = b.colA and a.ColB = 'Somevalue'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SQL,
But my advice here is:
`Less code + Less lines + Less words always gives better performance`,
This rule is working in every language.