# Weird SQL code: Why do they use a subquery instead of join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I met the following MySQL code:

```
SELECT ServiceFee
FROM Shows
WHERE ID = (SELECT ShowID FROM Orders WHERE ID = ?)
```

It makes me wonder because the people who wrote this code usually use SQL joins. I would rewrite it

```
SELECT ServiceFee
FROM Shows
INNER JOIN Orders ON Shows.ID = Orders.ShowID
WHERE Orders.ID = ?
```

My question: Is there any reason why this code was written with a subquery and whether it is completely safe (producing the same result in all situations) to rewrite it with the join?

Are there any caveats?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052596/subquery-v-s-inner-join-in-sql-server

Comment: @I_am_Batman - that post is for a different DB engine

Comment: @TudorConstantin, the same concepts apply, don't they?

Comment: It depends on what types of optimizations each of the dbs have implemented and how they implemented it. What works in MySQL might or might not work in sql server, and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there are no caveats. As a matter of fact, the [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.codersrevolution.com/blog/MySQL-performance-INNER-JOIN-vs-subselect) query might run faster

Comment: As long as \`ID\` column is guaranteed to be unique in \`Orders\` table..,

Answer (score 3):

"Is there any reason why this code was written with a subquery"

a very long time ago MySQL joins used to be slow

Comment: I doubt that suqueries were faster back then

Comment: joins were so slow that it was faster to do one query, gather the IDs then do another query with " IN (?,?,?,?) "

no longer true, fortunately

Answer (score 2):

Without a context the two queries don't do the same. If `Orders.ID` is not unique, the first query might produce an error because the subquery can return multiple rows. If `Orders.ID` is unique (probably primary key) then there will not be any difference - neither in the result nor in the performance (with newer versions). So in this case it is just a question of preference. Usually i prefer joins. But in your example the subquery solution looks fine and readable. So i wouldn't rewrite it without a reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical reason to prefer a Subquery over a Join:

Between `Shows` and `Orders` there's a 1-many relation, when you switch to a join you usually must add a DISTINCT to get rid of the duplicate rows returned.

In your case this is not needed, because you restrict to a single order, but when you remove the WHERE-condition or change it to return multiple rows you will notice that.

Comment: Without the WHERE condition the first query will probably throw an error.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: Correct, must switch to `IN` instead.