# Equivalente to INNER

Tags: sql

I want to structure a query with no using INNER JOIN. I figured out that an INNER like this:

```
Select A.Name 
from A INNER JOIN B on (A.id1 = B.id1 AND A.id2 = B.id2)
Where B.id = @Id
```

produce the same as:

```
select A.Name 
from A 
where  
A.id1 in (select B.id1 from B where B.id = @Id)
and
A.id2 in (select B.id2 from B where B.id = @Id)
```

Isn't it?

Note that my question is not about if it is better or not, only if it is an equivalent or if there is not an equivalente for that INNER.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subquery v/s inner join in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052596/subquery-v-s-inner-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: Why?? Inner join is way better than subqueries.

Comment: My question is about equivalence of functionality, not about if it is better or not.

Comment: If inner joins are better than subqueries depends on dbms and other things.

Comment: You can not replace an INNER JOIN with an IN or EXISTS condition. They mean different things. Sometimes one can be rewritten to the other, but not always.

Comment: Please a_horse_with_no_name may be you are right ... please can you make your comment as an answer with a little bit of argumentation. THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second query may match id1 and id2 from different B rows, so that query may return rows not expected. You have to keep id1 and id2 together:

Use `EXISTS`:

```
select A.Name 
from A 
where exists (select * from B
              where A.id1 = B.id1 AND A.id2 = B.id2
                and B.id = @Id)
```

or "Row and table constructors"

```
select A.Name 
from A 
where (A.id1, A.id2) in (select B.id1,  B.id2 from B where B.id = @Id)
```

Comment: I´m not sure if it is the same as an INNER JOIN, are you?

Comment: @Ibai, probably better, because if it's a one to many relation, those queries will not return duplicate rows.

Comment: Thx @jarlh I agree with you, the "Row and table constructor" seems to be the correct (and may be better) way.

Comment: I, too, agree. This is the way to write the query. You want the name `FROM` A `WHERE` `EXISTS` a related record in B. (In other words: You want the name `FROM` A `WHERE` the tuple id1/id2 is `IN` the set of tuples in B.) This is the idea of SQL, that you describe what you are looking for.