# How to filter queryset based on related objects if it contains data in django

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I want to filter and get only those data related to its related objects data if only related to its parent object child objects have data. For eg:
I have the following models:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    date_of_collection=models.DateField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)

class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and i have data related to models as:

```
Collection:
+----+--------------------+
| id | date_of_collection |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | 2019-01-17         |
|  2 | 2019-01-30         |
|  3 | 2019-02-01         |
|  4 | 2019-02-02         |
+----+--------------------+

Products:

 +----+--------------------------------+
 | id | name           | collection    |
 +----+--------------------------------+
 |  1 | product 1      | 3             |
 |  2 | product 2      | 1             |
 |  3 | product 3      | 1             |
 |  4 | product 4      | 4             |
 +----+--------------------------------+

Price:

| id     | price            | product               |
+--------+------------------+-----------------------+
| 1      | 10.00            | 1                     |
| 2      | 20.00            | 1                     |
| 3      | 12.00            | 3                     |
+--------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

here I have price related to only `1` and `3` product so I only want those products based on queryset that i only want to filter based on specific date_of_collection.

I have tried the following queryset:

```
collection_month = Collection.objects.filter(date_of_collection__month=2)
product = Product.objects.filter(collection_id__in=collection_month).exclude(price_set__price=None)
```

is it the way I do or some next way.. it gives sometimes bad result. How do I do it.

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close.
You shouldn't compare `collection_id` with actual collection items - you can just pass `collection__in=collection_month`.
You can directly exclude products without `price` with `price__isnull=True`

This query will use subquery (`WHERE`):

```py
collection_month = Collection.objects.filter(date_of_collection__month=2)
products = Product.objects.filter(collection__in=collection_month).exclude(price__isnull=True)
```

This query will use `INNER JOIN` which is [rumored to be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052596/subquery-v-s-inner-join-in-sql-server):

```py
products = Product.objects.filter(collection__date_of_collection__month=2).exclude(price__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my database has some condition that really requires `collection__in` to check for data. I hope `.exclude(price__isnull=True` won't work we should use `price_set__price__isnull=True` else we get `django.core.exceptions.FieldError`

Comment: @dipbazz did you actually check results? It's working just fine on my end. I can send you my unit test that shows it's working.

Comment: It is also working for me but the thing is I have to use `related_name__fields` to look up its related objects. I just cannot access the fields of the child objects directly from parent objects.

Comment: @dipbazz Can you bring example of in what query you can't access fields of the child objects from parent objects? What you want to fetch?

Comment: As I have set my `related_name` in foreignkey fields of price models my `related_query_name` will be defaults to the value of `related_name` as stated in [documentaion of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) So, I have to use related name instead of model name in lookups.